# Is this Linux copy command redundant and invalid?

Tags: linux, shell, command, cp

I want to update my Wordpress site using SSH and I read in a blog how to achieve it.

But before anything else, I want to confirm if this is a valid Linux copy command. Because I am not sure. I will explain why..

*here's the syntax* - **`cp -rpf -f /WordPress3.9.1/* /wordPress3.9.2/`**

according to the blog, this command will "**Copy the updated files and overwriting the old files**"

notice that there are TWO **-f** flags.. according to http://explainshell.com/ the **-f** flag tells the copy command that if an existing destination file cannot be opened, remove it and try again. I am not sure if having 2 **-f** flags in the **cp command** syntax is redundant and invalid. please help!

according to http://explainshell.com/

> **cp** - copy files and directories
>
> **-R, -r, --recursive** - copy directories recursively
>
> **-p** - same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
>
> **-f, --force** - if  an  existing  destination  file cannot be opened, remove it and try again (redundant if the -n option is used)

Comment: Yes, the two `f` flags are redundant. Why do you assume that makes them invalid?

Comment: Anyway, this is not an programming question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-f is just a flag. Specifying it twice is just going to cause the flag to be set twice; there's nothing wrong with this, and it is functionally the same as only specifying it once.

Some options like -v increment a variable value, which would make two uses different from one use, but this is not the case for -f.

Comment: That's what I assumed. @Keith Thompson Having two -f flags would make it different from having 1 -f flag in a cp command syntax. Thank you nneonneo for clarification.